# What is the best tool to create a bootable ISO

Tags: software-recommendation, live-usb

First, the OS target:  Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

the end goal is an ISO that I can mount on a VMware machine that boots into this linux with a few customizations.

I looked at [linux-live](https://www.linux-live.org/) first, which is the subject of this question, but am open to other tools if I am chasing the wrong one.

With LL, I have successfully created the ISO however it does not boot with VMware.  The documentation says you should execute this script:

```
root@sm:/a/linux-live/tools# ls
isolinux.bin.update
```

However I cannot figure out what "URI" it wants.

```
root@sm:/a/linux-live/tools# ./isolinux.bin.update 

--------------------------------------
Add directory to isolinux search paths
(for example /slax/boot):
```

The script itself says it's for debian, I wondering if there is a difference with ubuntu.

```
# This script will update the file ../bootfiles/isolinux.bin to match
# your LiveKit name
#
# Requires: Debian
#
```

So...

1. is there an easy fix for the isolinux.bin.update script?
2. a better way to go about this?

Comment: You might want to [edit] the title; "*best*" is highly subjective and questions that would attract only opinion based answers are not supported here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script you link is available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/Tomas-M/linux-live/blob/master/tools/isolinux.bin.update) for anyone looking to follow along. It gets some packages and sets up some directories, but the directory it's prompting for appears to be used in this piece of code:

```
for file in fs/iso9660/iso9660.c fs/lib/loadconfig.c elflink/load_env32.c; do
   sed -i -r 's:"/",:"'$DIR'",\n\t"/",:' $file
done
```

This looks like it's using `sed` to search for instances of `"/` and replace a given directory name.

It seems to be looking at a file that contains default paths like this (from [GitHub](https://github.com/geneC/syslinux/blob/5e426532210bb830d2d7426eb8d8c154d9dfcba6/core/fs/lib/loadconfig.c#L16))

```
static const char *search_directories[] = {
    NULL,           /* CurrentDirName */
    "/boot/syslinux",
    "/syslinux",
    "/",
    NULL
};
```

I think this means if you gave it a value of say `/foo` it would turn this into paths like `/foo/boot/syslinux`, `/foo/syslinux` and `/foo` as paths that syslinux will use by default.

To answer your question about the differences between Ubuntu and Debian in this respect it makes no real difference. Both use essentially the same boot process as far as I am aware.

> a better way to go about this?

Possibly an easier way to do what you want is to simply use VirtualBox/VMWare to install Ubuntu and then copy the resulting disk image to a USB bootable medium. You may also be able to simplify that a bit by simply telling VirtualBox or VMWare to do USB passthrough or mounting that USB medium as a disk that can be seen during the installation process.